# Showcaseview in multiple fragment which is inside view pager under same activity?

Tags: android, showcaseview

I am having problem to show  [showcaseview](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView) demo view on every fragment which is inside view pager.I am seeing showcase view can only be initialized with activity and creates a single instance.So if i hide showcaseview in on fragment then it hides on all fragment's showcaseview.

Comment: Do you want the views at the same time and hide them after each other? Why don't you just want to show them one after each other? You can do this using a listener.

Answer (score 1):

ShowCaseView can be initialized in fragment and pager. In the fragment(inside the pager) add this:

```
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        view.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                new ShowcaseView.Builder(getActivity())
                        .setTarget(new ViewTarget(R.id.list_shurela_tracks,getActivity()))
                        .setStyle(R.style.YourStyle)
                        .singleShot(ShowcaseView.Type)
                        .setContentTitle("Just touch")
                        .setContentText("Touch to ....")
                        .hideOnTouchOutside().build();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: doesn't work for me...I have 3 fragments ,in the second i do the same as you,This covers my first fragment @Momin Al Aziz

Comment: Sorry I moved out of android for quite some time now. But as far as I remember the ShowcaseView Library was getting deprecated that time. You can take a look at https://github.com/deano2390/MaterialShowcaseView